# Telegram API edit message

Tags: telegram

Is there a way to edit messages in [telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api)? I couldn't find a solution in https://core.telegram.org/methods.

Comment: You provided the resources and links to answer your own question.

Comment: @CharlieFish that link does not have the required method

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu Then there is probably no way....

Comment: @CharlieFish see answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The required method is :

```
messages.editMessage#ce91e4ca flags:# no_webpage:flags.1?true peer:InputPeer id:int message:flags.11?string reply_markup:flags.2?ReplyMarkup entities:flags.3?Vector<MessageEntity> = Updates;
```

[see here for updated Telegram API functions & types](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/master/Telegram/SourceFiles/mtproto/scheme.tl)